# Creating double type registration for customer in ruby on rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a rails app where i want the `customer` to be able to register an account of type `personal` or `business` . I have 3 models: `Customer`, `PersonalAccount`(where i store info for personal account), `BusinessAccount`(where i store info for business account). A customer can have one personal account and one business account. I would like to create two page of registration, one for customer with `fields_for` personal account, like `/personal`, and one for customer with `fields_for` business account like `/business`. How can i proceed?

Comment: Could you show us what code you've written? Do you have controllers methods for these pages? Are you using any sort of authentication libraries like Devise?

Comment: I've created the three controllers following the RESTful pattern.Used nested attributes to create the  association to use in the form. My question is how i can create a page with a form for "customer + personal nested attributes" and a form for "customer + business nested attributes". Do i need to create these 2 action in the customer controller? Or there is a way to create two instance od the customers#new action?

Comment: The cleanest way to do this is two actions in the controller.

Comment: Or two controllers, each with a new method.

Comment: I think i will create two controller, the cleanest way as you say. Thanks

Comment: @Luidi Versitelli I moved my advice in these comments to an answer if you want to be able to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation a possible way to handle this in a neat way is to use two controllers.

You can then define the RESTful routes for each controller, and handle the business logic difference inside them.

If it turns out the two controllers have a lot of the same logic, consider putting that logic in a mixin or parent class for the two to inherit from.